# JS code to display file path on a hidden upload file field

Tags: javascript, upload

I used the [Shaun Inman's method](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom) to create a customized "upload file" button, and it works just fine.

Trouble is, this method doesn't display the file path that the user has uploaded.

Can anyone help me with a simple JS code to have the file path displayed when selected.

Comment: The path (that is being displayed in some browsers like FF) is client-side only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of browsers do not send up the file path for security reasons, that is why you are not seeing it.

[IE8 value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) depends on security zone

Comment: DO you have any idea how do I go about it then>/

Comment: i want the user to see that he/she uploaded the correct file and that it was uploaded successfully

Comment: Well you are not going to get the path, that is how the browser's are doing it these days.